# how do I query a sqlite db in go?

Tags: sqlite, go

I'm trying to get an array of "Search" structs.

```
type Searches struct {
    id int
    count int
    search string
}
func get_recent_searches(db *sql.DB, limit int) []Searches {
  var searches []Searches
  var query = "select from searches brder by count desc limit ?"
  st, err := db.Prepare(query)
  result, err := st.Exec(limit)

  if err != nil { panic(err) }

  /*
  for rows.Next() {
    item := Searches{}
    err2 := rows.Scan(&item.id, &item.count, &item.search)
    if err2 != nil { panic(err2) }
    searches = append(searches, item)
  }
  */
  
  return result
}
```

Here is the error:

`src/main.go:72:2: cannot use result (type sql.Result) as type []Searches in return argument`

Comment: I am not sure I understand what's the question here.

Comment: trying to get an array from sqlite

Comment: I see that you mentioned at the top also `I'm trying to get an array of "Search" structs` but is the current code giving any error or are you not able to figure out the approach?

Comment: i get an error and I'm not able to figure out

Comment: please add the error in that case

Comment: i added error to post

Comment: @chovy the error message is pretty clear, given that Go is a typed language you cannot return the variable `result` which is of type `sql.Result` from a function whose return type you declared as being `[]Searches`.

Comment: no idea how to fix.

Comment: To me it looks like you are missing some basic understanding of the Go language, it's type system and the database/sql package. My hint, try a db.Query instead of a db.Prepare followed by a st.Exec and rework on the part you have commented out to solve your problem. In general, Exec is used for statements like INSERT or DELETE and the returned value is related to the effect of the statement executed, like result.RowsAffected() or result.LastInsertedID(). Use Query for statements that return rows.

Answer (score 1):

This link explains how to use SQLite with go: https://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/content/en/05.3.html

But the error you are seeing is because your function is defined as

```golang
func get_recent_searches(db *sql.DB, limit int) []Searches {}
```

It must return `[]Searches` (a slice of Searches structs). (NB I would probably name a single search result as `Search`).

Adding the fixes suggested by @Peter Gloor (Query to return rows, rather than an Exec to change data) and removing the limit placeholder, your code could be

```golang
func get_recent_searches(db *sql.DB, limit int) []Searches {
  searches := make([]Searches,0)
  query := "select * from searches order by count desc"
  st, err := db.Prepare(query)
  if err != nil { panic(err) }
  rows, err := st.Query(limit)
  if err != nil { panic(err) }

  for rows.Next() {
    item := Searches{}
    err2 := rows.Scan(&item.id, &item.count, &item.search)
    if err2 != nil { panic(err2) }
    searches = append(searches, item)
  }
  
  
  return searches
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3" // Import go-sqlite3 library
)

// Searches ...
type Searches struct {
    id     int
    count  int
    search string
}

func getRecentSearches(db *sql.DB, limit int) []Searches {
    var searches []Searches
    row, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM search ORDER BY count LIMIT ?", limit)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer row.Close()
    for row.Next() { // Iterate and fetch the records from result cursor
        item := Searches{}
        err := row.Scan(&item.id, &item.count, &item.search)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        searches = append(searches, item)
    }
    return searches
}

func main() {
    searchDB, _ := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./search.db") // Open the created SQLite File
    defer searchDB.Close()                            // Defer Closing the database

    // Get and print the first 5 records to the console
    searches := getRecentSearches(searchDB, 4)
    fmt.Printf("ID\tCount\tSearch\n")
    for _, item := range searches {
        fmt.Printf("%d\t%d\t%s\n", item.id, item.count, item.search)
    }
}
```